# Ajax call url in an external js file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a web page (written in php / codeigniter) that uses some javascript code.

I tried to move some javascript code to external file to better manage the code.
So in document ready event I load external file with

```
$.getScript('<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/offerta_editScontirow.js');
```

one piece of code, putted in an external js file, does not work; instead it works correctly if I put all the code inside the main php file.

```
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '<?php echo site_url("Offerta/applica_sconti");?>',
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data, status, xhr)
        {
 ........
```

It does not work because it does not elaborate the php code, and in the query string I find

> "php echo site_url("Offerta/applica_sconti");?>:"

So, is there a way to have it works? May I pass any parameter to the external js file while loading it, and pass the url to be used in ajax call? Some other method?

Kind regards,
Matt

Comment: You can pass a JavaScript variable if you declare it before the external JS file. Something like `<script>var url = <?php echo site_url("Offerta/applica_sconti");?>; </script>` And then you can use it in your AJAX call

Comment: @Ionut I added this line to the main php file:
            'var url_applicasconti = '<?php echo site_url("Offerta/applica_sconti");?>';
            $.getScript('<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/offerta_editScontirow.js');'

I modified the js file in this way:

'$.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url_applicasconti,
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data, status, xhr)
        {'

but when I execute the page it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: url_applicasconti is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `window.my_url = 'some value';` and get the variable like below

```
window.my_url = '<?php echo site_url("Offerta/applica_sconti");?>';

$.getScript('<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/offerta_editScontirow.js');
```

and

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: my_url,
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data, status, xhr)
        {
```